# Idiomatic way to build up an array/list based on prior index in Scala

Tags: scala

I am trying to build up a time series using an autoregressive formula in Scala. The equation looks to the prior index of the target array and the current index of two other arrays. Example dummy equation: 
`z_i = z[i-1] - x[i] + y[i]`

It is straightforward in an imperative style (see C++ example below) but I am trying to figure out the idiomatic way in Scala. I have created a solution with a `while` loop but it feels clunky and un-Scalaesque.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> x {1, 2, 3, 4};
  std::vector<int> y {10, 9, 8, 7};
  std::vector<int> z {0, 0, 0, 0};

  for(int i = 1; i < x.size(); i++) {
      z[i] = z[i-1] - x[i] + y[i];
  }

  for(auto i: z) {
      std::cout << i << std::endl;
  }
}
```

```
// Desired result
[0, 7, 12, 15]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of modifying an existing `z`, you'll want to build it from `x` and `y`.

```
val x = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4)
val y = Vector(10, 9, 8, 7)
val z = (x.tail zip y.tail).scanLeft(0){case (nz,(nx,ny)) => nz - nx + ny}
//z: Vector[Int] = Vector(0, 7, 12, 15)
```